# ActionBar menuitems doesnt work using support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

my menu layout looks like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:blabla="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item android:id="@+id/msg_action_sections"
          android:title="Sections view"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          blabla:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="Search"
          blabla:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
          blabla:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

but eclipse keeps giving me this error : "Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat 
 library"

I don't know how to tell Eclipse that I'm using it!!! In android studio it worked, but I can't use Android studio. So what should I do?
Thank you

PS: Im using support.v7.app.ActionBar and my Activity extends from ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out, problem is, that I had bad theme using in AndroidManifest. You have to use Theme which uses Appcompat as parrent:)